# An $L-$function and a $J-$function. Related?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation, l-functions

Consider a Dirichlet series for a non real character of modulus $q$

$$ L(s,\chi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s} $$

and $s\in\Bbb C$ with real part greater than one.

Consider a $J$-series $$ J(s,\chi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}} $$

which converges for $\Re(s)<0.$

> Is there a relationship between the analytic continations of $L$ and $J$?

I think that the analytic continuation of $J$ will be partly expressible as a sum of $L-$functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downvoted because your second series doesn't converge. You meant $\chi$ is a  Dirichlet character and $$J(s)=\sum_n (e^{-\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}}-1), \qquad\Re(s) > 1/m$$ where $m$ is the first integer such that $\chi^m$ is principal.

Then expand  $$e^{-\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}}-1=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(-\chi(n))^k n^{-sk}}{k!}$$ and change the order of summation to get a series of Dirichlet L-functions.

Comment: I think it converges for $\Re(s)<0$ actually.

Comment: Furthermore I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: No, and it does. Try with $\chi(5n)=0,\chi(5n+3^m)=i^m$

Comment: Then what is the maximal analytic continuation of $J?$

Comment: Could you add more information? Like the formula for the maximal analytic continuation for $J(s,\chi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}}$ ?

Comment: and you probably know the answer to this (feel free to answer it): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368647/what-is-the-analytic-continuation-of-varphis-sum-n-ge-1-e-ns

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}}$ doesn't CONVERGE. I was tired, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{-\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}}-1)$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}^*$  and has an essential singularity at $0$